# MySql backup is not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql, backup

```
String[] executeCmd = new String[] { "mysql", "-u",DB_USER,"-p"+DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME, " < ", "\""+FileName+"\"" };

Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
System.out.println("processComplete: " + processComplete);
```

This is the code I have worked with. The program hangs when the "waitFor()" method is called.

How to solve this?

Comment: That sounds fine, `waitFor()` waits for mysqldump to finish running, which can take hours for a large database.

Comment: is it working when u run from command line manually

Comment: @elber : it works manually in the command prompt. 

BTW ,its a small database with single table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String[] command = new String[]{"mysql", Constants.DB_NAME, "-u" + Constants.DB_USER, "-p" + Constants.DB_PASSWORD, "-e", " source "+FileName };

    try {
            Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
            if (processComplete == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("DatabaseManager.restore: Restore Successfull");

            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("DatabaseManager.restore: Restore Failure!");
            }

        return true;

    }

    catch (final Exception ex) 
    {
        Application.showErrorInConsole(ex);
        NmsLogger.writeErrorLog("Database Restore failed ", ex.toString());
        NmsLogger.writeDebugLog(ex);
        return false;

    }
```

The above code worked fine for me :)

Answer (score 5):

you need to add spaces after the parameters, don't use array

```
String executeCmd = "mysqldump ", " -u ",DB_USER," -p " + DB_PASSWORD, + " " + DB_NAME, " < ", "\""+FileName+"\"" ;
```

and the cleaner way is to use `String.Format()`

```
String executeCmd = String.Format("mysqldump -u %s -p %s %s < \"%s\"", DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, FileName)
```

Comment: Are you sure? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format. `String.format("%s does support it!", "java")`

Comment: @elber i already edited the answer. the original `string.format` I showed was in `C#`

Comment: You said it does not support, not like for C#, that is why i posted.

Comment: @elber ok ok, my mistake. i tried it on netbeans but it failed that's why i said it's not working but i realize the syntax was incorrect. java uses `%s or etc` while `c#` uses `{0}, {1}, etc..`

Comment: A space after `-u` is optional. If you have a space after `-p` it means `mysqldump` will prompt for a password. If the password is specified on the command line (as is the case here) you must not use a space after the `-p` parameter.

Comment: @JohnWoo Sorry to say this doesnt solve the issue. still the program gets hang

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't set a password for XAMPP, don't use -p

```
public class Testbackupmysql {
public boolean tbBackup(String dbName,String dbUserName, String path) {

    String executeCmd = "C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump -u " + dbUserName + " --add-drop-database -B " + dbName + " -r " + path;
    Process runtimeProcess;
        try
        {
            System.out.println(executeCmd);//this out put works in mysql shell
            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

                if (processComplete == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
                }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Testbackupmysql bb = new Testbackupmysql();
        bb.tbBackup("your_database_name","your_db_username","D:\\123.sql");

}
```

}