# how to replace a string value in java

Tags: java, string

i replace a particular string in a statement like the following

```
SQL = SQL.replaceAll("CUSTOMER_NUMBER", customer);
```

this conversion goes as integer but i want to replace this as a string like the following

```
AND CIMtrek_accountlist_customer_number = '0002538'
```

but at present it replaces like the following

```
AND CIMtrek_accountlist_customer_number = 0002538
```

how to do this in java.

Comment: I can only recommend using [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: Why at all you are required to do this??  Can you post surrounding code to explain the scenario? And if at all you want to pass parameter in your SQL Query, Use `PreparedStatement`, to avoid getting attacked by `SQL Injection`.

Comment: We all wan't to prevent [this](http://xkcd.com/327/) from happening ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get it to output the ' as well as the customer variable

```
SQL = SQL.replaceAll("CUSTOMER_NUMBER", "'" + customer + "'");
```

However as @jlordo mentioned in a comment, you should look at using prepared statements which will allow you to inject values into a prepared sql statement.

Comment: And use of prepared statement will avoid `SQL Injection Attack`.

Answer (score 1):

Though you should be using `PreparedStatement` if you are running SQL, However if placeholder `"CUSTOMER_NUMBER"` is under your control, It is better to use String.format. See and example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format)