# equivalent of String.Format() in Java

Tags: java

I have this peace of code :

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM utilisateurs WHERE pseudo = '" +  pseudo.getText()+ "' AND password = '" + new String(password.getPassword()) + "'";
```

My question is : isn't there any other method to concat these variables with the string ?

In C# I was using the method String.Format() method as :

```
String query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM utilisateurs WHERE pseudo = '{0}' AND password = '{1}'", pseudo.getText(), new String(password.getPassword()));
```

Comment: First, yes.  There's a way.  Second, don't do this with SQL.  Use `PreparedStatement` instead.

Comment: @Makoto how can I use PreparedStatement in java ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Also, [hash and salt your passwords](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).  Do not store plaintext passwords in databases.

Comment: Your SQL query appears vulnerable to [injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`String.format()` can be used to format Strings, [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

```
public static String format(String format, Object... args)
```

> Returns a formatted string using the specified format string and arguments.

However when it comes to building SQL query strings the preferred way is to use `PreparedStatement` ([Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)) as it:

- protects you from SQL injection
- allows the database to cache your query (build the query plan once)

Your code using a `PreparedStatement` might look like below:

```
final PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT * FROM utilisateurs WHERE pseudo = ? AND password = ?");
pstmt.setString(1, pseudo.getText());
pstmt.setString(2, new String(password.getPassword()));
final ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: okey, but when I used the query as a string, I used `ResultSet result = st.executeQuery(query);` to execute it, how can I excute that query if I used PreparedStatement ?

Comment: Call `executeQuery()` on the `PreparedStatement` instance (updated the code snippet).

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, `String.format` is the direct equivalent, but you should use a `PreparedStatement` instead. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html):

> In the following example of setting a parameter, con represents an
>   active connection:
>
> ```
> PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE EMPLOYEES
>                                   SET SALARY = ? WHERE ID = ?");
> pstmt.setBigDecimal(1, 153833.00)
> pstmt.setInt(2, 110592)
> ```

Using a `PreparedStatement` instead of `String.format` will protect your code from SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Java has [similar method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to format your strings. `String.format()`

However, if you choose to use `PreparedStatement`, you can read the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

From the documentation:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET SALARY = ? WHERE ID = ?");
pstmt.setBigDecimal(1, 153833.00)
pstmt.setInt(2, 110592)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, as others have mentioned as well, use String.Format, here is a good resource for that: [How to use java.String.format in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format).

However, in this particular example, the real answer is not to do string substitution, but to use arguments in the SQL statement.

Something like:

```
query = 
String query = "SELECT * FROM utilisateurs WHERE pseudo = ? AND password = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, pseudo.getText());
ps.setString(2, password.getPassword());
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```