# Replace in string

Tags: java, string

I have a string s composed of two strings s1 and s2, `s = s1+s2`.

I'd like to be able to modify `s1` in another function, and then recompose `s` with the modified version of `s1`. I'd like to change `s1` so that it takes `s2` as a paramater. For example, `s1 = "1+"` and `s2="2"`, and I'd like s to become `"incr(" + s2 + ")"`.

I could do that by using `s1 = "incr(%s2%)"` and then `s1.replace("%s2%",s2)`, but what if `s1` already contains `"%s2%"` ? I'd like it to be as generic as possible.

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Please format your code. It is difficult to read.

Comment: I think you could use String.format() function
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format

Comment: over my head .. can you please describe in an easier way :S

Comment: Why not `s1 = "incr(" + s2 + ")"; `?

Answer (score 4):

`String` is an immutable class, meaning you cannot modify it. All String methods create a **new** `String`, instead of modifying the `String`.

You could however use `toCharArray` (or `StringBuilder` for more flexibility), which is mutable.

Comment: But my question is how to create a new string whose content depends on s2?

Comment: It is a pretty common approach. The wording for placeholders in Property-files is i.e. ${myVariableName}

Answer (score 0):

If you want editable `Strings` in Java, use `StringBuilder` class ([http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). That has multiple methods for mannipulation and replacing substring.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringBuffer` if synchronization is required or else use `StringBuilder` to reduce the overhead of synchronization. Both are `mutable` classes. They have many methods to modify the content of `String`.