# Replace instances of character in a string with array values

Tags: java, arrays, string

How would i go about replacing all instances of a character or string within a string with values from an array?

For example

```
String testString = "The ? ? was ? his ?";

String[] values = new String[]{"brown", "dog", "eating", "food"};

String needle = "?";

String result = replaceNeedlesWithValues(testString,needle,values);

//result = "The brown dog was eating his food";
```

method signature

```
public String replaceNeedlesWithValues(String subject, String needle, String[] values){
    //code
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `//code (..for you to attempt)`

Comment: I'd give this a shot
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format

Comment: nope. not homework. I could attempt to write something that uses a lot of substrings but i know there's a more efficient way to go about doing this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using `String.format`:

```
public static String replaceNeedlesWithValues(String subject, String needle, String[] values) {
    return String.format(subject.replace("%", "%%")
                                .replace(needle, "%s"),
                         values);
}
```

:-)

Of course, you'll probably just want to work with `String.format` directly:

```
String.format("The %s %s was %s his %s", "brown", "dog", "eating", "food");
// => "The brown dog was eating his food"
```

Comment: This is clever... I like this.

Comment: perfect. thank you. I knew there was a better way than finding the positions of the needle and then using substrings.

Comment: @David Of course, but this also illustrates that you'd be far better off using `String.format` directly in your code (use `%s` as your placeholders rather than `?`). :-)

Comment: could you edit your answer to show that? i've not worked with replace() or format() before

Comment: @David Sure thing. (The `replace` was simply to replace your `?` with `%s`; general usage would not require using `replace`.)

Comment: Or, you can just pass the `values` array as the second argument.

Comment: thanks a ton @Chris. I was still trying to incorporate replace() into and it wasn't working out. Thanks Eric, i'll check that out.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young could you look at my edit? If my values are enclosed in apostrophes the method puts brackets around it. How do i prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

If your string contains patterns that need to be replaced, you can use the appendReplacement method in the Matcher class.

For example:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String[] tokens = {"first","plane tickets","friends"};
String text = "This is my 1 opportunity to buy 2 for my 3";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
for(int i=0; m.find(); i++) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, tokens[i]);
}
m.appendTail(sb);
```