# Print a formatted string

Tags: java, string

The code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str = "<html>" +
                "           <head>" +
                "               <title>" +
                "                   %s" +
                "               </title>" +
                "           </head>" +
                "           <body>" +
                "               %s" +
                "           </body>" +
                "   </html>";
        String str1 = String.format(str, "Home","Hallo");
        System.out.println(str1);
    }
```

I want to print the **`str1`** as follows

```
//The str1 should need to print like this


           <html>           
                <head>              
                    <title>                 
                        Home                
                    </title>        
                </head>     
                <body>              
                    Hallo           
                </body>
            </html>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: A perfect duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format

Comment: Yes it is possible, just add a new line character `\n` at the end of every String.

Comment: "_newline character_" is the term you're looking for...

Comment: Consider the str is a large html ; whether any method than that of adding \n

Comment: Can you add `\t` and `\n` in the input string (`str`) or do you need them to be generated automatically?

Comment: @A4L str is a string ;; u said to add \n to every String...

Comment: He meant adding `\t` and `\n` to each part of the string. For example `<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<title>...`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Manually it is possible if the string is a large one what i do???

Comment: Look at Theolodos' answer. He did exactly what I meant. If the file is large you can still add them with some piece of code (add `\n` after each character `>`, or use `String#replaceAll(">", ">\n"))`.

Comment: Thanks for ur valuable answer.@Theolodis

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid adding `\n` all over the place in big HTML string manually then you can use [**`OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint()`**](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/io/OutputFormat.html#createCompactFormat%28%29) in **dom4j package**:

```
public String prettyHTMLPrint (String html) {  
    if (html==null || html.isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("xml null or blank in prettyHTMLPrint()");
    }
    StringWriter sw;
    try {
        OutputFormat format = OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint();
        format.setSuppressDeclaration(true);
        org.dom4j.Document document = DocumentHelper.parseText(html);
        sw = new StringWriter();
        XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(sw, format);
        writer.write(document);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error pretty printing html: " + e, e);
    }
    return sw.toString();
}
```

**For your example it prints this formatter HTML:**

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Home</title> 
  </head>  
  <body>Hello</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
String str = "<html>\n" +
"           <head>\n" +
"               <title>\n" +
"                   %s\n" +
"               </title>\n" +
"           </head>\n" +
"           <body>\n" +
"               %s\n" +
"           </body>\n" +
"   </html>\n";
```

this is what you want... if you are on windows, you might need to add an addiotional \r after the \n.

`\n` is called the newline character, `\r`is called carriage return. The `\n` is the standard newline character on unix and windows, but some programs under windows might need the carriage return dto display your string properly.

`System.getProperty("line.separator");` will return `\n` on unix and `\n\r` on windows, it simply returns the standard "line separator" of the operating system this command is executed on.

Comment: Or rather use `System.getProperty("line.separator");`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the 2 Values hardcoded, you can use this:

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    final String SEPARATOR = "\r\n";
    builder.append("<html>").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("           <head>").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("               <title>").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("                   ").append("Home").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("               </title>").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("           </head>").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("           <body>").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("               ").append("Hallo").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("           </body>").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("   </html>").append(SEPARATOR);
```

The dynamic way could be sth. like this:

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    final String SEPARATOR = "\r\n";
    builder.append("<html>").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("           <head>").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("               <title>").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("                   %s1").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("               </title>").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("           </head>").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("           <body>").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("               %s2").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("           </body>").append(SEPARATOR);
    builder.append("   </html>").append(SEPARATOR);

    String str = builder.toString().replace("%s1", "Home").replace("%s2", "Hallo");
```