# What is the Java equivalent to printing values in C#?

Tags: c#, java, printing

In C#, I can say:

```
 int myInt = 10;
 int myInt2 = 20;
 Console.WriteLine("My Integer equals {0}, and the other one equals {1}", myInt, myInt2);
```

And I know how to print things in Java like this:

```
 int myInt = 10;
 System.out.println("My Integer equals " + myInt);
```

So how do I combine the two so that in Java, I can print multiple values just like I would in C#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 16):

You can call `String.format` explicitly:

```
System.out.println(String.format(
    "My Integer equals %d, and the other one equals %d", myInt, myInt2));
```

Comment: You beat me to it! +1

Comment: Just curious - why wouldn't you just use 'printf' (Ryan's answer) ?

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Because this came to mind first.  Or possibly if you needed to do other thinks with the same string, or didn't want to look up if whatever you're working with has its own format function, and if it uses the same format specifiers as `String.format`.

Comment: @Servy: Thanks - just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some subtle difference.

Answer (score 9):

Dont forget the `printf` statements..

```
int myInt = 0;
int myInt2 = 20;

System.out.printf("My Integers equal %d, and the other one equals %d\n",
                               myInt, myInt2);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was just a simple example of the printf. I'm still trying to get used to Stack Overflows convention when answering questions :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `+` to display multiple variables

```
int myInt = 10;
int myInt2 = 20;
System.out.println("My Integer equals " + myInt 
                    + "and second integer is " + myInt2);
```

Comment: @ therealtbs : There's nothing wrong with showing an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

You may try [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class. Your code which is almost the same as your C# code should look something like this:

```
int myInt = 10;
int myInt2 = 20;
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("My Integer equals {0}, and the other one equals {1}", myInt, myInt2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Read up on formatting of strings in java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html

Essentially, instead of using the index-based formatting approach in C#, you add format specifiers which are processed in the order they exist in the string.  For example:

```
System.out.format("My integer equals %d, and the other one equals %d", myInt, myInt2);
```

Java uses different specifiers for different value types.  `%d` (used above) indicates integer values. `%s` would be a string, `%f` would be a floating-point value, etc.  More details can be found in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

```
int myInt = 10;
int myInt2 = 20;

System.out.println("My Integer equals " + myInt + ", and the other one equals " + myInt2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String formatter, so by working on your example, I will do this:

```
int myInt = 10;
System.out.format("My Integer equals %d %n", myInt);
```

And if we converted the C# code to java, it will look like:

```
int myInt = 10;
int myInt2 = 20;
System.out.format("My Integer equals %d, and the other one equals %d %n", myInt, myInt2);
```

even more advancing, you can format the float with `%.2f` and format the int with `%03d` and much more.