# Printing OTHER values in Java

Tags: java, printing

So, now I know that for integers I can use

```
 System.out.println("Name: %d", Name);
```

So, how do I print out other values in Java? Things like Strings, Boolean, Dates, and Doubles? Do I use %d for integers only?

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format refer to docs at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Answer (score 3):

Regarding:

```
System.out.println("Name: %d", Name);
```

No, that won't work for println, for **printf**, yes, but not for println:

```
System.out.printf("Name: %d", Name);
```

or if you want a new line:

```
System.out.printf("Name: %d%n", Name);
```

---

For booleans, %b, for doubles, %f, for Strings %s .... Dates would require a combination of specifiers (or I would just use a SimpleDateFormat object myself). Note that these specifiers can take width constants to give them more power at formatting the output. e.g.,

```
System.out.printf("Pi to four places is: %.4f%n", Math.PI);
```

Please check the [Formatter API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for more of the details.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(whatever);
```

`whatever` can be a String, boolean, int, Point, whatever. Check out the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html).

Answer (score 0):

Anything you put inside the parenthesis of System.out.println() or System.out.print() is formatted and printed as a string. However, you can control how variables are printed out inside your string (as you did using %d) using Java's printf() method.

The printf() method takes two parameters: the string to print and a list of variable names.  You insert the format flags (%d, %f, etc) in the string and you list the variables you want formatted in the string second.

```
System.out.printf("Your total is %d", 29.99);
```

This means that Java will format 29.99 as a decimal rather than a string when it outputs "Your total is 29.99".

You can check out the other types of formatting in the "conversion type character" table [here](http://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can do `System.out.println("something");` if you want to skip a line after printing, but if you want to print something, then continue on the same line, then you should just do `System.out.print("something");` You can also just print out Strings, boolean values (t/f) and doubles just by doing something like
`System.out.println(booleanname);`    or
`System.out.println(Stringname;` or
`System.out.println(doublevariablename);`