# How to display whole double value?

Tags: java, android, numbers, double

My double value is something like **0.000659** and it show up like **6.6e-05**.

I have looked all over but because I don't know what it is doing, I don't know what to look for.

Does anyone know what it is doing or how to fix it?
**My code**:

```
Double value= jsonObject.get("last").asDouble();
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "value"+value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: This can be done with Java string formatting. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format/3695253#3695253

Comment: What does BterLast mean?

Comment: @ twlkyao it was a variable i used in my app which i forgot to change to value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Double value = jsonObject.get("last").asDouble();
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(Locale.US);
String res = formatter.format("%+0.6f", value);
```

res will be something like `"0.000659"`

Comment: whats sb for in new Formatter?

Comment: "sb" is something that crept in all on its own.  I have removed it.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
    System.out.println(String.format("%.6f", value));
```

Note that `6` indicate how many decimal places you want to display.