# Java GUI inputs to HTML bill

Tags: java

I am working on a project for a business. Using Java application, I am planning generate a sales bill. This is how it is going to work.....

[image]

When I run my java application, GUI window will popup and it will ask me to enter details to generate bill......after hitting submit button some background processing should happen and it should redirect me to

[image]

all data enter should be replaced by variable shown on the second pic, I also have code ready to generate this page in HTML.

Not able to figure out how to make this work.

Comment: Have you tried with String.replace() method?

Comment: @Nomanaliabbasi Ohh! not really.

Comment: Better yet, if you're generating your HTML content within Java code, [take a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format)