# Android: setText destroys formatted string

Tags: android, string-formatting, android-view, settext, text-formatting

I'm new to android programming and I'm working on an financial management app. Currently I got into a problem that the setText() method destroys the string format that I pass in.

I have an Account class which has a customary toString method which returns a formatted string of the account information:

```
public String toString(int colWidth1, int colWidth2, int colWidth3) {
    return String.format("%-" + colWidth1 + "s", myDisplayName) +
            String.format("%-" + colWidth2 + "s", myBalance) + 
            String.format("%-" + colWidth3 + "s", myInterestRate);
}
```

And in the AccountInfo activity, I have:

```
// create a table that contains all account information of the current user
    TableLayout accountTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout_account_details);
    List<Account> accountList = accountManager.getAllAccounts(CurrentUser.getCurrentUser().getUserName());

    // for each account, display name, balance and interest rate
    for (int i = 0; i < accountList.size(); i++) {
        Account account = accountList.get(i);
        TableRow accEntry = new TableRow(this);
        Button accButton = new Button(this);
        accButton.setText(account.toString(10, 10, 10));
        Log.i("account info", account.toString(10, 10, 10));

        // button format
        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, -7, 0, -10);
        accButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        accButton.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

        // add button to the row
        accEntry.addView(accButton);

        // add row to the table
        accountTable.addView(accEntry);

        // ...more code here for button click listener
    }
```

Although my logcat prints nicely formatted string as I wanted, the text on button does not line up nicely

(just realized I don't have enough reputations to post a screenshot of my app...)

I've tried to debug for long but still don't have a clue. Any help is deeply appreciated!!!

**EDIT**: screenshot

> [image]

Comment: I think you should check this link to know how to use String.Format http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format

Comment: @CuongHuynh well is there anything I did wrong though?

Comment: my fault. Do you meet problem with the column/textview width?

Comment: I just added a dropbox link of my screenshots, that might make my question clearer

Comment: @Kedarnath Can you put up my other screenshot too? It's missing one for the app and I don't have enough reputation to put up by myself...

Comment: @user3435663 sure, please give me the link here in comment.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5rxcz6sglsfdlig/vl93tmxGk6

Comment: @user3435663, you welcome, Its done.

Comment: You should use [multicolumn listview](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview/) please check the link. Right now you are using single textView, instead if you use multiple Textview, then your problem should be solve.

Comment: @Kedarnath Thank you for the link! That looks really helpful! But I also want the whole row as one clickable item, i.e no matter if I click on the name, balance or interest rate, I will be directed to the next activity. That's why I originally tried to setText on a button. Is there any way to achieve that? Thanks again!

Comment: You may call same activity on each textview ,that's way you can solve it.

Comment: well there's a time restriction before I can accept my own answer. will do though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My roommate points out the problem! He's awesome!!!

The alignment is off because the font is not monospaced. Simply do

```
android:typeface="monospace"
```

in the layout xml and problem solved!!!

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer from Android Studio:

Do not concatenate text displayed with setText. Use resource string with placeholders.

When calling TextView#setText:

Never call Number#toString() to format numbers; it will not handle fraction separators and locale-specific digits properly. Consider using String#format with proper format specifications (%d or %f) instead.

Do not pass a string literal (e.g. "Hello") to display text. Hardcoded text can not be properly translated to other languages. Consider using Android resource strings instead.

Do not build messages by concatenating text chunks. Such messages can not be properly translated.