# I'm trying to make a GUI in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

So I am trying to make a GUI in Java. I am pretty new to Java GUIs. So here is my code:

```
private class thehandler implements  ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){//this is what is going to handle an event
        String string = "";

        if(event.getSource() == item1)//if they click enter on item1
                string=String.format("field 1: %s", event.getActionCommand());
        else if(event.getSource() == item2)//if they click enter on item2
            string = String.format("field 2: %s", event.getActionCommand());
        else if(event.getSource() == item3)//if they click enter on item3
            string = String.format("field 3: %s", event.getActionCommand());
        else if(event.getSource() == passField)//if they click enter on passField
            string = String.format("Password field is: %s", event.getActionCommand());
        }
}
```

I get an error on string=String.format("field 1: %s", event.getActionCommand()); and all the other String.format lines. It says "The method format(String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)"

I have no clue how to fix this. I just downloaded the JRE and JDK 8 if that helps at all. 
Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use java.String.format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format)

Answer (score 1):

Simply convert it to a string

```
event.getActionCommand().toString()
```

Alternatively (without stringFormat):

```
string="field 1:" + event.getActionCommand();
```

Comment: getActionCommand returns a String already. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html

Answer (score 1):

You are using String.format() the wrong way. To see how it should be used (applicable to your use case), consult this question (and answers):

[How to use java.String.format in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format)