# i have a DAO and i am retrieving values in select query how to print it in database in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have a select query where i am retrieving column values like

```
select city,state,country from abc
```

and then fetching it using result set

```
city=rs.getString(1),state=rs.getString(2)
```

and so on

Now have to print like I live in city in state in country in java

can i give this way like

```
String a="I live in %city% in %state% in %country%"
```

will it work using %% symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to use string concatenating operator `+` as below:

```
String a="I live in" +city+ "in" +state+ "in" +country;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, % wont work in java.. You have to concat strings..and our +(plus) operator do that job in java

```
String a="I live in "+city+" in "+state+" in "+country;
```

Comment: Can you add explanation in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = "I live in " + city + " which is in " + state + " and in " + country + " Country";
```

Look at [this tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) for further details.

Comment: @user13763 because %% syntax is used in like operator in MYSQL not in JAVA

Comment: In string literals if you want to add some data in between then you ll have to use `+` to concate the string. and as per @TruePS %% is used to match any part /place of word in MySql or Postgresql with `like` or `ilike`. If you want to use it then you will have to use `String.format`.

Comment: @user13763 : see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format